# Calling a network State check from other activities

Tags: android, class, android-activity, timeout, network-state

I realize this question has been answered before but couldn't find an answer that deals with my specific case.

I want to create a class called "InternetConnectionChecks" that will handle checking a network state and http timeouts. I'll call the methods twice in the app (once at the beginning to get data from a server, and once at the end to send user orders to the server).

For good form I'd like to put all these methods in a single class rather than copy/paste at different points in my code.

To check the network state, I'm using ConnectivityManager; thing is, getSystemService requires a class that extends Activity.

```
package arbuckle.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class InternetConnectionChecks extends Activity {

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if ((activeNetworkInfo != null)&&(activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

QUESTION: I need to use this code in classes that are NOT activities; in fact I want to set up this method in a separate class that is not an activity. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create util class with static method

```
public class Utils{

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ((activeNetworkInfo != null)&&(activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

usage inside activities

```
boolean isNetworkAvailable = Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this);
```

Comment: Got it! My gap was understanding how to refer to the class in activities.